# Using computed property as value of ember handlebars input helper, deleting part returns undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

Seems simple enough but it's been driving me crazy. I have an input helper in my view:

```
{{input value=contact.fullName type="text" style="text-align:left;"}}
```

And in my `contact` model I have these properties and this computed property:

```
firstName: DS.attr('string'),
lastName: DS.attr('string'),

fullName: function (key, value, previousValue) {
    if(arguments.length > 1){
        var nameParts = value.split(/\s+/);
        this.set('firstName', nameParts[0], this.get('firstName'));
        this.set('lastName', nameParts[1], this.get('lastName'));
    }
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
}.property('firstName', 'lastName')
```

Great so I type "Joe Bob" into my input and it's updated all over the page.
But when I delete "Bob" I get this in my input: "Joe undefined". This doesn't happen if I delete "Joe", if I do that I just end up with " Bob".
**How can I keep it from putting `undefined` into my view?**

Been at this for 2 days, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So changed the return on the function, this allows the user to delete the whole input, which was what my goal was.

```
fullName: function (key, value) {
    if(arguments.length > 1){
        var nameParts = value.split(/\s+/);
        this.set('firstName', nameParts[0]);
        if(nameParts[1]===undefined){
            return this.get('firstName');
        }
        this.set('lastName', nameParts[1]);
    }
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
}.property('firstName', 'lastName')
```

The return on undefined, means that from that point forward it only returns the first name, which neatly takes care of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it works when you delete Joe because there's an space before Bob, so, you end up with a string like ' Bob', and when you split the value inside the if, it uses the space before the B, that's why it works. And it doesn't work when you delete Bob because there's no space after Joe, so, when you try to access nameParts[1], it returns you 'undefined', that's why you get 'Joe undefined'. You could try something like this:

```
this.set('firstName', nameParts[0], this.get('firstName'));
this.set('lastName', nameParts[1] || '', this.get('lastName'));
```

you will end up with 'Joe ', with an extra space at the end, if that works for you, then that's fine, otherwise you'll need to remove the extra space.

Comment: I had tried this already, and it doesn't work because it doesn't allow the user to delete the entire field without deleting extra spaces. It doesn't let them enter their first name either, as after the first character is entered it auto puts a space.